# What's the difference between "This book I have not read" and "This book has not been read by me"?

Tags: sentence-construction

> This book I have not read

> This book has not been read by me

Can someone explain the difference between those sentence? Are they have the same meaning with different form? And for the "this book I haven't read," what is this form called?

Comment: I can't think of any context where one of your suggestions might actually *mean* something different to the other. But neither are very likely things to say, compared to ***I have not read this book*** (standard Subject + Verb + Object, which is the most common construction in English).

Comment: It should be emphasized, and others have already mentioned it, that you generally usually wouldn't use _either_ of those choices.

Comment: Does your native language not contain simple passive sentences? I doubt that.

Comment: "This book I have not read" is a phrase, because it does not have a main verb.  (You *could* interpret it as a very poetic way of saying "I have not read this book", as FumbleFingers says, but it's very old-fashioned and not something you are likely to encounter now.)   "This book has not been read by me" is a complete sentence, because it has a subject and a main verb.

Answer (score 1):

**This book I have not read** *could* be used as a way of saying "I have not read this book" (as FumbleFingers commented). But it is not at all a common way to phrase that meaning; if that was the meaning intended it would be very awkward to say it that way, unless in a poem or song. Instead, I would hear it as setting up a contrast: "*This* book I have not read, *that* book I have." The emphasis is on the book rather than the person.

**This book has not been read by me** is less ambiguous in usage: it means "I have not read this book." But it uses the passive voice, which sounds strange for such a simple idea.